# Product/system to make tutorials for how to use your website

Tags: javascript

If I'm not mistaken, I once stumbled across a product or something that let you make tutorials for your website using Javascript. Like, you could show the user directly how to do certain things with a virtual cursor, in-browser. Am I making this up, or is this a real thing?

Sorry if this question doesn't belong here (StackOverflow claims that it looks subjective and is likely to be closed).

Comment: if you have "your" word on your question `SO` robots think that it is subjective:) don't worry about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for this: http://amberjack2.org/

EDIT: More info here http://ajaxian.com/archives/amberjack-2-0-on-page-tutorials

Comment: This might've been it! So, is this like, not released to the public yet or something?

Comment: No, it's available for use, have a look at the link I just added to my post for more info.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this answer - why? The question may have been off topic, but based on takua108s response to this answer, I've clearly answered their question.